# bash - How to align text with printf into columns with non-ascii characters?

Tags: bash, printf

How can I make `printf` to align values into columns even with non-ascii characters?

The following commands should align values in the 2nd and 3rd paramter to fixed 20-character width:

```
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" "Foo" "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" "Fooo" "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" "Foooó" "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" "Foooóó" "Bar"
```

I would expect the following to be printed:

```
Foo                  Bar
Fooo                 Bar
Foooó                Bar
Foooóó               Bar
```

In reality, this gets printed:

```
Foo                  Bar
Fooo                 Bar
Foooó               Bar
Foooóó             Bar
```

For some reason any non-ascii character (such as `ó` in my example) shortens the column by 1 character.

Comment: What encoding are you using?

Comment: @user1934428 I reproduced the problem using UTF8.

Comment: @adamsfamily : This seems to be the unfortunate, but [supposed behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350240/why-is-printf-shrinking-umlaut) of `printf`.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 - this is really unfortunate. `printf` is printing characters (not bytes) therefore it should count characters (not bytes) - IMO.

Comment: @adamsfamily : This is my opinion too. My personal guess is that the standardization by POSIX tries to keep backwards compatibility with old scripts, and if you remember the early times of Unix (before the introduction of _locale_), multi-byte-handling was everything else than straightforward. Probably, the bash `printf` just relied on the `printf` function in the C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Non-ascii character e.g. `ó` is not printed like ASCII that are single width characters.

One solution is to use `tab` character in between 2 strings in `printf` and pipe output to `column`:

```
prnt() {
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Foo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Foooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Foooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fooooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Foooooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fooooooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Foooooooooo" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóóóóóó" "Bar"
    printf "%-20s\t%-20s\n" "Fóóóóóóóóóó" "Bar"
}
 
prnt | column -t -s $'\t'
```

[**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/6gbY94)

**Output:**

```
Foo                   Bar                 
Fooo                  Bar                 
Foooo                 Bar                 
Fooooo                Bar                 
Foooooo               Bar                 
Fooooooo              Bar                 
Foooooooo             Bar                 
Fooooooooo            Bar                 
Foooooooooo           Bar                 
Fóó                   Bar                 
Fóóó                  Bar                 
Fóóóó                 Bar                 
Fóóóóó                Bar                 
Fóóóóóó               Bar                 
Fóóóóóóó              Bar                 
Fóóóóóóóó             Bar                 
Fóóóóóóóóó            Bar                 
Fóóóóóóóóóó           Bar
```

Comment: The problem is that this does not scale. This only pretends to work when the number of utf8 characters is less than the tab size. Try this: https://pastebin.com/uSzd2MWq

Comment: @adamsfamily: Please check updated answer and linked demo. We just need to pipe output of `printf` to `column` command.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use awk.  Awk's `printf` appears to understand unicode better than bash's printf.  Try:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
awk 'BEGIN{
printf "%-20s %-20s\n", "Foo", "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n", "Fooo", "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n", "Foooó", "Bar"
printf "%-20s %-20s\n", "Foooóó", "Bar"
}'
```

When run, this produces columns that line up:

```
$ sh script.sh
Foo                  Bar                 
Fooo                 Bar                 
Foooó                Bar                 
Foooóó               Bar
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me at all. Produces the same out put as before. Please look at this: https://pastebin.com/kudGnZZN (running on macOS)

Comment: @adamsfamily OK.  I see.  On MacOS, you have BSD awk which is a completely different codebase than the awk I'm using (GNU awk).  You could get this to work by installing GNU awk, called `gawk`, via homebrew: `brew install gawk`.  I don't have a Mac so I'm sorry I can't be more help.